How to identify liquidity add/remove instructions in Raydium and OpenBook AMM transactions?
Question:
I'm working on a project to parse transactions on Solana, specifically to identify addLiquidity and removeLiquidity instructions for Raydium and OpenBook. Here is the code I am using:
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { SolanaParser } from '@debridge-finance/solana-transaction-parser';
import { Idl } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import raydiumIdl from './idl/idl.json';
import fs from 'fs';

const connection = new Connection('QUICKNODE_URL', 'confirmed');

const raydiumProgramId = new PublicKey('CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C');
const openBookProgramId = new PublicKey('675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8');
const txParser = new SolanaParser([{ idl: raydiumIdl as unknown as Idl, programId: raydiumProgramId.toString() }]);

const logFilePath = 'log.csv';

fs.writeFileSync(logFilePath, 'Transaction Signature,Instruction Type,User Public Key,Instruction Details\n');

async function fetchAllTransactions(address: PublicKey): Promise<any[]> {
  let before: string | null = null;
  let allSignatures: any[] = [];

  while (true) {
    const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(address, { before, limit: 1000 });
    if (signatures.length === 0) break;
    allSignatures = allSignatures.concat(signatures);
    before = signatures[signatures.length - 1].signature;
  }
  return allSignatures;
}

async function processTransactions(address: PublicKey) {
  try {
    const signatures = await fetchAllTransactions(address);

    for (const { signature } of signatures) {
      try {
        const parsedTransaction = await txParser.parseTransaction(connection, signature, false);

        if (parsedTransaction) {
          console.log(`Transaction: ${signature}`);
          console.log(`Parsed Instructions: ${JSON.stringify(parsedTransaction)}`);

          for (const instruction of parsedTransaction) {
            const programId = new PublicKey(instruction.programId);
            if (programId.equals(raydiumProgramId) || programId.equals(openBookProgramId)) {
              if (['addLiquidity', 'removeLiquidity'].includes(instruction.name)) {
                const userPublicKey = instruction.accounts.find(account => account.name === 'userOwner')?.pubkey.toBase58();
                const instructionDetails = JSON.stringify(instruction);
                const logEntry = `${signature},${instruction.name},${userPublicKey},${instructionDetails}\n`;
                fs.appendFileSync(logFilePath, logEntry);

                console.log(`Transaction: ${signature}`);
                console.log(`Instruction Type: ${instruction.name}`);
                console.log(`User Public Key: ${userPublicKey}`);
                console.log(`Instruction Details: ${instructionDetails}`);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (innerError) {
        console.error(`Error processing transaction ${signature}:`, innerError);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching transactions:', error);
  }
}

const poolAddress = new PublicKey('9JChDXVNfGTH6LqKP79T1JrvrQx5gXNAHMaVuNUNMwA4');
processTransactions(poolAddress);

I'm struggling to identify the specific instructions for adding and removing liquidity for OpenBook. How can I correctly identify and parse these transactions? What am I missing?
(Note: The QUICKNODE_URL is hidden for security reasons.)
